# SQL case when expression between?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, between

Is there a way to do something like:

```
DECLARE @x INT;
DECLARE @y INT;
SET @x=45;
SET @y=30;

SELECT 
    CASE @x - @y 
       WHEN BETWEEN 2 AND 3 
          THEN 'true' 
          ELSE 'false' 
    END
```

I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @x - @y BETWEEN 2 AND 3 
            THEN 'true' 
            ELSE 'false' 
       END
```

Answer (score 2):

`CASE expr WHEN val THEN ...` only works for equality check, not for more complex conditions like `BETWEEN`. In your canse, you need use a construct like `CASE WHEN val BETWEEN ... THEN ...`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @x - @y BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
SELECT CASE @x - @y
    WHEN 2 THEN 'true'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```